# Arabic text from SQL server data bases which don't support Arabic

Tags: java, sql-server, character-encoding, arabic, ebcdic

I have an issue with some .txt files exported from a vb6 application which use Arabic characters.

The vb6 application stores Arabic data in an sqlserver databases which doesn't support Arabic encoding, so all data are stored as an unrecognized characters. When I retrieve this data in a txt file to use them in an other application I can not find the why to decode the unrecognized.

The same file that I use, is used by an ibmOS400 application, the file is read well. Someone tell me that there is a set of table in which you can find all characters and there translation into Arabic.

In IBM OS400, I have to change the encoding to IBM-420 to read Arabic by my java application.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to make column datatype type NVARCHAR OR NTEXT. WE have same issue and it is fixed .
Happy coding